# How can I make a chocolate material similar to this one?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, transparency

I would like to make a chocolate material similar to the one seen in the picture.
[image]

The problem is the slight transparency (you can see the nuts shine through on the surface), which I just can't acchieve.

Could somebody help me or tell me which node I have to include?

Thank you

Comment: Thats a tough one, there is a lot going on. The only way I can see to do it is to model basic geometry and then you would have to texture paint the majority of it. Keeping in mind where your displacement mapping would be. maybe @richsedman can help out, he is a master of this type of stuff.

Comment: Perhaps a translucent surface object over the nuts objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the transparency you need to combine volumetric scatter into the material - in place of the usual 'diffuse' shader.

[image: final]

The key to the transparency is to model the "chocolate" to that it has very thin layers over the "nuts".

I started by modelling the nuts :

[image: just the nuts]

Then added the chocolate (just a cube, rescaled), subdivided and used Sculpt mode to build up the chocolate around the nuts.

[image: sculpted chocolate]

The material to include surface properties (the bumpiness and glossiness) along with the translucency is as follows :

[image: material]

Adjust the Density (the Value node) to vary the opaqueness of the chocolate. This is essentially just the same as a volumetric shader that you would use for a liquid - just with a higher density to make it appear more solid.

For best results, take care over the sculpting of the chocolate over the embedded nuts - you need consistently thin layers to get smooth transitions.

Blend file included [image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried a similar approach, using a volumetric.

[image: choc nuts]

I made the nuts first as an array (they could be distributed around another mesh for shape). The nuts get a yellow material that should affect the subsurface light.

[image: nuts]

Then I shrink wrapped a plane with solidify modifier for depth.

[image: modifiers]

I added a volumetric with a chocolate gloss as well as a clear coat. I am only using scatter as its quicker to render than absorption.

[image: choc nodes]

More nuts:

[image: more nuts- rocky road]